# Language Translator RESTful API returning first sentence twice

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, language-translation, machine-translation

Using REST with Basic Auth and a FormUrlEncoded payload with multiple 'text' entries (essentially, a word document represented as 8 sentences), when I call the API it returns the translations, but it returns the first sentence twice leaving the translated array out of sync with the initial request. Is there something basic that I'm missing?  I am stuck on .net40 too.

```
var payload = new FormUrlEncodedContent(watsonValues);
var translationResponse = _watsonClient.PostAsync($"{_watsonBase}/v2/translate", payload).Result;
if (translationResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var responsePayload = translationResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    var watsonTranslations = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WatsonMtResponse>(responsePayload);

    foreach (var translation in watsonTranslations.Translations)
    {
        translatedList.Add(translation.Translation);
    }
}
else
{
    translationResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
}
```

Comment: Could you add an example of the request and response data?  Also, can you elaborate on the .net40 issue?

Comment: @Chris I switched the request to use a JSON payload and it worked as expected.  Prior to that I was using a Form Encoded header request with multiple text elements.  The .Net 4.0 issue is related to the use of the Watson Libraries/SDK which I can't deploy against existing systems due to various conflicts with the older version of .NET we're using.

Comment: Cool.  If switching to Json works for you, you could add that as your own answer and accept it.

Comment: Thanks @Chris.  Still getting the hang of StackExchange, appreciate the nudge!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I addressed the issue by making the request Json based rather than the FormUrlEncoded request I made previously.  The code is basically...

```
var translationResponse = _watsonClient.PostAsync($"{_watsonBase}/v2/translate", 
                new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mtRequest),
                Encoding.UTF8,
                "application/json"))
                .Result;

            if (translationResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var responsePayload = translationResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                var watsonTranslations = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WatsonMtResponse>(responsePayload);

                foreach (var translation in watsonTranslations.Translations)
                {
                    translatedList.Add(translation.Translation);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                translationResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            }
```

And the Json object looks like this...

```
 class WatsonMtRequest
 {
    [JsonProperty("model_id")]
    public string ModelId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("text")]
    public List<string> Text { get; set; }
 }
```